# How assembly language distinguish Numbers from Asci letters?

Tags: assembly, logic, nasm, computer-science, cpu-architecture

for example if i have a 32 bit register eax that have value 49 stored inside it and i  print the value stored it will print 1 in Asci. but also at the same time i can use this register for calculation like adding and substracting

does write sys call or print function trigger any sort of conversion from  numbers to asci letters?

Comment: The  letter `'1'` is represented by the number 49.  The only conversion that takes place is when your display device choses to render character 49 in the shape of a “1” sign.

Comment: Short answer - It doesn't. Both "numbers" and ASCII are stored in a binary format. Without context, binary data can represent anything from a number to a character, a pixel, or even an address. It's not the job of assembly to give context to data. It's the job of the programmer to understand the context of the data they operate on.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a property of assembly language itself, but of the operation of the processor and the machine code program that the processor is executing (independent of the source code language that was used).

Further, it isn't necessary for the processor to know whether data is ascii codes or raw numeric data.

Why?  Because the program is in control of what's happening.  It tells the processor how to interpret data, whether to print, what to print, when to convert what series of ascii digits into a number or vice versa: when to expand what number into a series of ascii digits.  It is the program's job to know that this data is ascii and that data is numeric — and as necessary, it will tell the processor different treatment of data (say, byte vs. word) by the specific instructions in the machine code for the program.

*A program can have logic errors*, meaning sometimes programmers write a program that will send simple/raw 1 to the I/O device — which doesn't print well — instead of adding 48 making 49 so a '1' digit will be printed.  The processor doesn't consider such things as an error and simply does what it's told in that regard.

High level languages have a concept of types, which can help prevent such errors — assembly language has fewer such preventions.